# Using curl with TLS1.3

Tags: tls

I need to test my server with `curl` 8.2.1 utility.
My server works only with TLS1.3 and cipher 0x1302 - `TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`.
When I run `curl` it proposes many TLS ciphersuites that are not supported by my server (and TLS1.3) - for example (suites list of TLS-handshaking): 0xC028, 0xC027, 0xC014, 0xC013, etc. 
I run curl with command line:
`curl --http1.1 --tlsv1.3 --get https://my_ip:my_port`
The question is: how can I force `curl` propose need cipher suite (0x1302) ?

Comment: Isn't this information readily available [in the documentation](https://curl.se/docs/ssl-ciphers.html)?

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes, yes it is. Also I have tried to use the option '--tls13-ciphers TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384', but there was no effect in proposed cipher suites.

Comment: [Which TLS implementation](https://curl.se/docs/ssl-compared.html) does your curl build use? What you can configure/select for TLS depends on the implementation.

Comment: There should be no need to configure curl to only offer a single cipher in the first place. A TLS client should offer what it supports and a TLS server chooses from this offer, provided there is something the server can use. If your server assumes that the clients will only offer selected TLS version and ciphers then your server implementation is severely broken.

Comment: If my information is correct the client always sends the supported suites first for 1.3 so it cannot know which ones are supported by the server.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, which TLS implementation is used ? I have downloaded `curl` and built it using "defaults". In other words, I did not link it to any external lib (openssl or other).

Comment: It'll have detected openssl or gnutls in the configure step, else you wouldn't have TLS at all. Do you have a configure.log?

Comment: @Rup, the file `configure.log` is absent in my curl folder and subfolders. Files: `configure.` and `configure.ac` are exist only. What should I do to create it (`configure.log`) ? 
I doubt that I have no TLS support at all, because of cipher suites are proposed, but not from TLS 1.3…

Comment: You're right I meant config.log. If you don't have a config.log, how did you build it? The normal way would be `./configure && make`, and it looks like curl's ./configure doesn't work without an SSL choice either way.

Comment: @Rup, there no the `config.log` too. I have built it from the folder `winbuild` running VS 2019 command line shell: `nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static MACHINE=x64 RTLIBCFG=static`.

Comment: Oh right then you're using the built-in Windows TLS library, schannel. It looks like there is code to select ciphers, lib\vtls\schannel.c set_ssl_ciphers(). You could try adding debug trace to that to work out what's going on. It's also possible that schannel ignores what it's told and just uses default ciphers anyway, which at first glance it looks like you can configure globally in the registry.